# how can I create response curves using biomod2?

Tags: r, biomod2

I am using R version 3.6.0. I have made some biomod models. There is one factor among my environmental variables. When I am trying to create response plots this error comes up:

```
Error in subinfo == "MinMax" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

The code I use is:

```
SumGBMs <- BIOMOD_LoadModels(WgBiomodModelOut, models='GBM')
SumGBM_repcurves <- response.plot2(model= SumGBMs ,
                                  Data = WgBiomodModelOut,
                                  show.variables= get_formal_data(WgBiomodModelOut, dem),
                                  fixed.var.metric = 'median',
                                  col = c("blue", "red"),
                                  legend = TRUE,
                                  plot=T)
```

although I don't think that's the problem, but I have tried to use github biomod2:

```
devtools::install_github("biomodhub/biomod2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

but it did not work and the following erro0r showed up:

```
Error: Failed to install 'biomod2' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/NP/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAtIiba/file70c6f00293b/biomod2_3.4-03.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can you tell me what goes wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not giving to `response.plot2` function what it expects.

`Data` should be a data.frame with the same explanatory variables than the one used in model fitting process

`show.variables` should be the name of the explanatory viarable you want to display in the response plot

Maybe something like that will work:

```
SumGBMs <- BIOMOD_LoadModels(WgBiomodModelOut, models='GBM')
SumGBM_repcurves <- response.plot2(model= SumGBMs ,
                                  Data = get_formal_data(WgBiomodModelOut, 'expl.var'),
                                  show.variables= get_formal_data(WgBiomodModelOut, 'expl.var.names'),
                                  fixed.var.metric = 'median',
                                  col = c("blue", "red"),
                                  legend = TRUE,
                                  plot=T)
```